# Why is my MySQL database adding empty rows?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mamp

I'm learning PHP and SQL by running MAMP on my Mac, and accessing the database through phpMyAdmin.

I've made one PHP script to add a new user to a table, one for comparing inputted data with the table (login) and one to close an account. All of the scripts are very basic and the data isn't sanitized at all, as I'm just getting used to the basics of PHP.

I've noticed that after I run the script for account creation (inserting data), a few seconds after the script is run, a new row is added to the table with an id (which I've set to auto increment) but no other data.

I'm just wondering if the reason for this is something obvious in MySQL that I'm just missing.

The following is the account creation script:

```
<?php
//Get values from HTML form
$varUsername = $_POST['username'];
$varPassword = $_POST['password'];
$varPasswordHash = password_hash($varPassword, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

//Establish connection to database
$server = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$database = "members";

$connection = mysqli_connect($server, $username, $password, $database);
if(!$connection)
{
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

//Send data to database
$action = "INSERT INTO details (USERNAME, PASSWORD) VALUES ('$varUsername', '$varPassword')";

if(mysqli_query($connection, $action))
{
    echo 'Account created.';
}
else
{
    echo 'Account creation failed: ' . mysqli_error($connection);
}

mysqli_close($connection); //End connection to database
?>
```

and the HTML form to go with it:

```
<html>
<body>
    <form action="sign_up.php" method="post">
        <input type="text" name="username">
        <input type="text" name="password">
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you share that script with us?

Comment: Either you have a trigger on that table or some loop logic you are missing inserts an extra record.Share the code,no matter how teribad.

Comment: Have you tried debugging? Please show your HTML code as well. You should try print_r($_POST) in the very first line and see what your POST data is. I think you're not getting the desired POST data.

Comment: The problem is not in the code you are sharing with us. So what are you not showing us?

Comment: OMG, read about [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) and [mysqli prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) ASAP

Comment: I've added the HTML and I'll try what you mentioned Object Manipulator. Alon, I mentioned in the post that I haven't sanitized the data at all, but I'm aware that it's important.

Comment: Can I ask why you are hashing the password entered and then ignoring the hashed password?

Comment: Do you get blank row after pressing the SUBMIT button with nothing entered in the username and password fields. You do not checks that any data has actually been entered

Comment: RiggsFolly, yes sorry I should have changed that back. I was sending the hashed password but I tried sending it unhashed to see if that was the problem, but it wasn't.

Comment: Yes, pressing the submit button with empty text fields has the same effect.

Comment: It might be useful to see the scheme for that table as well, does that allow blank data to be entered to the tabel?

Comment: A good first step could be to add `echo $action;` above your `if` statement, to determine whether your query is being filled as you would expect.

Comment: So you are saying you get empty rows even if you actually enter data in username and password???

Comment: No, if I enter data, the correct data is inserted into the table, but if I leave the fields empty, it creates a new row with an ID but nothing else (the same as it does automatically after an account is created).

Comment: Sorry **Sarg** but there are a few obvious errors in this code that would not have been made if you had completed a few simple PHP tutorials. I suggest you _hit the books and tutorials_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm making a guess right now...

I would add an extra if-statement to the script itself. Like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit-form'])) {
    // All the above to insert the data into the script...
}
```

It would make sense if you visit the `sign_up.php` itself and notice there is a new entry made into your database.

You'll have to modify your HTML a little, to make the if-statement work.

Just add `name='submit-form'` to the submit button: `<input type="submit" name="submit-form">`

This will make the script more complete.

Also a little update on the matter as I just read that it adds an empty row after you submit an empty form.

You can check wether the fields are filled in with, guess what, another if-statement:

```
if (empty($_POST['username'])) {
    echo 'Please enter your username...';
} else
if (...)
```

Answer (score 0):

You do not verify if the POSTed values have anything in them, thus submitting an empty form results in an empty entry in the DB with just the ID.